# How to map a stateful ejb 3.1 session bean using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, ejb-3.1

I have a doubt on how to represent my database using JPA annotations with hibernate. It's a very simple webapp representing an online library.

I have a stateful session bean that allows users to reserve books. Users can reserve up to 2 books. It has the following fields:

- Integer id;
- UserBean userBean;
- List bookList;
- Date reservationDate;
- Date reservationExp;

The database representing this class is:

- int id_book_reservation PK
- int id_user FK
- int id_book FK
- date reservation_date
- date expiration_date

This stateful bean may work as a shopping cart. So it allows user to put books there, continue browsing, add another book and then finally ask for reservation (like the "buy" action on a e-commerce website).

I cannot figure out how to map the bookList field. The relation between reservation and books is ONE-TO-MANY but I was wondering how then it could be possible to know, for instance, when a book is already reserved since I have a List and not simply a book object (in a HQL).

Thanks in advance!
Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing 2 concepts of EJB/JPA up. 
A statefull session bean, is a entity that is managed by the container. Here you can keep the state for a certain time, until the statefull session bean is expired.
Your database tables should be represented in Entities. An [entity](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html) is a POJO with annotations (or xml config). In those annotations, you specify your table characteristics, primary and foreign keys.
So move the fields that map your table to another class and then you can use your statefull session bean to keep your state.

Good luck

Comment: Just to add, you need to think about your data and how it should be represented in the database, in addition to thinking about how your java entities should be factored.  The mapping will then be between your java model (JPA Entities) and your database tables.  Using tools like Dali in Eclipse can help with this mapping.